# Is there an easier way to "extract" type literals?

Tags: haskell, data-kinds

This works:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, PolyKinds, KindSignatures, GADTs #-}

import GHC.TypeLits

data F :: Symbol -> * where
    F :: F s


unF :: SingI s =>  F s -> String
unF g = fromSing $ s g where
    s :: SingI s => F s -> Sing s
    s _ = sing

val :: F "val"
val = F

main = print $ unF val -->> "val"
```

Can I write unF without the nested function somehow? Am I generally doing this "right"?

Comment: To get rid of the local definition, `unF = fromSing . (const sing :: SingI s => F s -> Sing s)` seems to work.

Comment: @raymonad Ok that's clever but it still needs another function to fix the type of sing - I was more looking for a way to do that.